# Issue with connection pool in weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, thread-dump

Hi while analyzing thread dump,
in server logs, I can see multiple issues like below

```
Error due to access to database: 

Caused by: weblogic.jdbc.extensions.PoolLimitSQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceLimitException: No resources currently available in pool NetCrackerDataSource to allocate to applications, please increase the size of the pool and retry..
```

If I see the thread dump multiple threads (around 90) are sleeping on a object weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.GenericConnectionPool.

```
"[MF]XPaxhItetorMde(4)" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f38880cf800 nid=0x3805 in Object.wait() [0x00007f381c846000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000070271c090> (a weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.GenericConnectionPool)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResourceInternal(ResourcePoolImpl.java:567)
    - locked <0x000000070271c090> (a weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.GenericConnectionPool)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:353)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.reserve(ConnectionPool.java:471)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.reserve(ConnectionPool.java:363)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPoolManager.reserve(ConnectionPoolManager.java:125)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPoolManager.reserve(ConnectionPoolManager.java:77)
```

Can anybody please help here to know what might be the possible issues, or any direction on how to progress?

Update: It is because connections in pool are used completely and not released. How can I know which processes holding up connections? Any help on this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your connection pool is exhausted. There is no sql connection available in the pool. Your application might not correctly release its connections. Check your code.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, thanks, how(or from which log) can I know which process(es) are holding up connections?

Answer (score 0):

Set up inactive-connection-timeout to a reasonable value (by default this is 0). This value will depend on your environment and the objective of it to wait for n Seconds until attempting to return a connection to the pool.

A warning and a stack trace will be looged by WebLogic when the application will hold a connection longer than the inactive-connection-timeout parameter

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the `weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.releaseResource` method is synchronized, meaning one thread will be executed at a time.

That part of the code is called, not only when trying to get a DB connections, but also, when trying to close a connection. In our situation we saw 21 threads trying to close their connections and struggling to get the lock.

Example:

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '37' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=--edited-- nid=--edited-- waiting for monitor entry [--edited--]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.releaseResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:651)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000702dff4f0> (a weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.GenericConnectionPool)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.release(ConnectionPool.java:780)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPoolManager.release(ConnectionPoolManager.java:177)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.doClose(PoolConnection.java:226)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.close(PoolConnection.java:139)
...
```

An Oracle note described a similar situation proposing a potential solution:

> This issue can be resolved by following these steps:
>
> 1. Set JDBC Driver parameter SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME to a low value (let's say 1 minute). For more details, please refer to the Note 151972.1
> 2. Enable "test Connections On reserve" for datasource.